# H.264 support for Opera and openSUSE

Tags: opensuse, codec, opera

I am using openSUSE Leap 42.2 and Opera 46.0.2597.57.

Some videos on the internet (maybe the half on YouTube) do not work on Opera.
YouTube tells me that I cannot watch the video and suggests me visiting https://www.youtube.com/html5.
*H.264* and *MSE & H.264* are not supported by my browser as the page mentions, although Opera is listed as suported.

I did some research and installed the following packages (which were not the sollution):

- chromium-ffmpeg-extra
- chromium-ffmpeg-extra-debuginfo
- chromium-ffmpegsumo

Maybe I need to mention that Firefox works pretty fine with YouTube and other videos that do not work on Opera.

Thanks a lot for your help.

PS:
If this issue is fixed with openSUSE Leap 42.3 this would be an option for me, but I still hadn't enough time for an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This unfortunately is a known problem in Opera spanning to `OpenSuse 42.3`.  YouTube reports that `H.264` and `MSE & H.264` both are unsupported when accessed from that OS.  This is using `Opera 46.0.2597.26`, not quite as fresh as yours, but newer OS.

Looking around the web, there is reference to a Chromium codec patch.  Uninstalling Chromium makes no difference on my setup, nor force reinstalling `ffmpeg` after uninstall of Chromium's extra codecs.  For those not feint of heart, there is a manual-linking solution `[1]` involving `libffmpeg.so`, which seems to have success there (but must be redone each time Opera is updated).  I have not tried the manual linking.

`[1]`  https://solus-project.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1004

Comment: More “unfortunately known problems”? No WPS and now this? Let's abandon Linux altogether. (not really, but I have enough of “unfortunately known problems”).

Answer (score 5):

I had same issue on Fedora 27, so I followed the instructions provided in link by @doug0 and tried out libffmpeg prebuilt with proprietary codecs. Here is essentials:

- go to https://github.com/iteufel/nwjs-ffmpeg-prebuilt/releases
- copy link to latest release (in my case 0.26.6)
- close Opera browser
- open terminal, and enter the following:

  ```
  $ curl -L -O https://github.com/iteufel/nwjs-ffmpeg-prebuilt/releases/download/0.26.6/0.26.6-linux-x64.zip
  $ unzip 0.26.6-linux-x64.zip
  $ sudo mv libffmpeg.so /usr/lib64/libffmpeg_h264.so
  $ sudo mv /usr/lib64/opera/libffmpeg.so /usr/lib64/opera/libffmpeg.so.orig
  $ sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libffmpeg_h264.so /usr/lib64/opera/libffmpeg.so
  ```
- verify that Opera now supports H.264 at https://html5test.com

Answer (score 1):

You can check your browser id at opera://about/ and download proper libffmpeg.so version from http://ppa.launchpad.net/saiarcot895/chromium-beta/ubuntu/pool/main/c/chromium-browser/.

For example my browser id is "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) **Chrome/69.0.3497.100** Safari/537.36 OPR/56.0.3051.52"  and I need libffmpeg.so from `chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_69.0.3497.72-0ubuntu1~ppa1~16.04.1_amd64.deb` . 
You should extract and replace (with backup) libffmpeg.so in your opera directory(in Debian /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/ ) and restart opera.

```
mkdir /tmp/libffmpeg
cd /tmp/libffmpeg
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/saiarcot895/chromium-beta/ubuntu/pool/main/c/chromium-browser/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_69.0.3497.72-0ubuntu1~ppa1~16.04.1_amd64.deb
ar x chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_69.0.3497.72-0ubuntu1~ppa1~16.04.1_amd64.deb
tar xJvf data.tar.xz
sudo cp -b ./usr/lib/chromium-browser/libffmpeg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/
```

Verify H.264 support at https://www.youtube.com/html5

## UPDATE: Ubuntu 19.10

In Ubuntu 19.10 (if you have Google Chrome installed) you can find the `libffmpeg.so` file in `/usr/share/code/`. So the command to provide Opera with support for H.264 YouTube videos (and Amazon Prime, Netflix, etc.) is

```
sudo cp /usr/share/code/libffmpeg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/libffmpeg.so
```

For Widevine support (Netflix, Amazon Prime) you'll need another Google Chrome file

```
sudo cp /opt/google/chrome/WidevineCdm/_platform_specific/linux_x64/libwidevinecdm.so /opt/google/chrome/libwidevinecdm.so
```

*Reference:* [Widevine + H.264 Support on Ubuntu 19.10](https://forums.opera.com/topic/36229/widevine-h-264-support-on-ubuntu-19-10)

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to keep coming up.  It happens, I research how to fix it, then forget about it, then it happens again.

This time I tried re-installing chromium-ffmpeg-extra which did not work for me but then I upgraded to opera 60.0.3255.27 which did work (today)

UPDATE:
the issue keeps coming up because every time opera upgrades it must be fixed again.

This time I found this thread: https://forums.opera.com/topic/27463/bug-html5-h-264-codec-videos-no-longer-working-on-opera-54-0-2952-41-ubuntu-18-04-lts-x86_64-xfce/7

Which recommended removing operas libffmpeg.so and creating a symlink to chrome's

These instructions may very based on where things are in your distro but for me running linux mint 18 I did this:

1. find opera dir and cd into it.
2. rename opera's libffmpeg.so to back it up
3. create symlink to chrome's libffmpeg.so

```
$ which opera
/usr/bin/opera
$ ls -al /usr/bin | grep opera
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          35 Jun  4 16:33 opera -> ../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera
$ cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera
$ sudo mv libffmpeg.so libffmpeg.so.bak
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libffmpeg.so
$ ls -al | grep libffmpeg.so
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root        38 Jun 11 06:53 libffmpeg.so -> /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libffmpeg.so
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   1799080 Jun  4 16:33 libffmpeg.so.bak
```

Obviously the important line is `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libffmpeg.so`  But I displayed the rest so that people could figure out how to know which directory they needed to be in.

Also I have chrome browser installed.  If you do not then you may have to install it for this solution to work.

I hope this is helpful.

I do not yet know if I will have to repeat these steps the next time opera upgrades ... probably.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to install the snap version of Opera (https://snapcraft.io/opera) this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I've created a script that patches Opera with the "libffmpeg.so" file from the package "chromium-ffmpeg-codecs-extra"
[Get it here](https://gitlab.com/Nesze/operaffier)

Comment: Downvoting his answer without giving a reason ? Not cool man ... but to user Nesze ...it could be due to your script being for a "Opera on Ubuntu platform" type solution whilst this question is focused on Opera in a OpenSuse context.

Comment: Yes it may be because of that. I'm rather new to linux, so I don't know what is common between these platforms, but I knew it worked for most ubuntu distros. I'm happily taking any feedback, just tell me what was wrong about it.

Comment: -> No issue man. At least you know some users will appreciate your effort. Keep it up buddy !!!

Answer (score 0):

::: Update 2019 :::

This "Opera  unable to play some  Youtube HTML5 videos in OpenSuse" issue still persists.

Opensuse 42.3+ fix ( as root , install this package. Other packages are not needed afaik ):

```
   # zypper -v in chromium-ffmpeg-extra
```

Then restart Opera (ensure all instances of Opera are closed ) and via Opera goto;

```
   https://www.youtube.com/html5
```

You should be able to see a Blue Tick besides the H264 and MSE & H.264 boxes to indicate that these codecs are now supported for the Opera browser.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the most suitable `libffmpeg.so` for Opera is contained by the snap package `chromium-ffmpeg` since the Snap version of Opera does use this version of `libffmpeg.so`.

I've written a shell script to copy the newest version of `libffmpeg.so`, which is included by the snap package `chromium-ffmpeg`, to the Opera library
directory. Please install `snapd` as well as the snap package by yourself first. You may also have to modify some paths to make the script work on your distro (mine is Debian 11.6).

Last but not least, RUN IT IN ROOT.

```
#!/bin/dash

MNT_DIR='/mnt/chff'
CHFF_PREFIX='chromium-ffmpeg'

mkdir $MNT_DIR

MAX_VER=0

for file in /var/lib/snapd/snaps/${CHFF_PREFIX}_*.snap; do
    CUR_VER=$(echo $file | sed -E "s|/var/lib/snapd/snaps/${CHFF_PREFIX}_||" | cut -f 1 -d '.' )
    if [ $MAX_VER '<' $CUR_VER ]; then
        MAX_VER=$CUR_VER; fi
done

mount -t squashfs -o ro /var/lib/snapd/snaps/${CHFF_PREFIX}_${CUR_VER}.snap $MNT_DIR

MAX_VER=0

for folder in $MNT_DIR/${CHFF_PREFIX}-*; do
    CUR_VER=$(echo $folder | sed -E "s|$MNT_DIR/${CHFF_PREFIX}-||")
    if [ $MAX_VER '<' $CUR_VER ]; then
        MAX_VER=$CUR_VER; fi
done

cp -v $MNT_DIR/${CHFF_PREFIX}-${MAX_VER}/chromium-ffmpeg/libffmpeg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/
```

P.S. The Snap version of Opera is buggy, that's why I have to bypass it.